# Find if a string starts with a specific pattern using regex in bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to use regext to detect if a string starts with a specific pattern or not but it does not work with me:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   line="{{ - hello dear - }}"
   if [[ "${line}" =~ ^\{\{\s*-\s*hello\s*.*\}\} ]]; then
        echo "got it "
   fi
```

In this example, I expect the if condition to detect that the line variable has a string that starts with "{{ - hello" and ends with "}}"
However, it does not do so as the echo message is not printed!

Comment: bash version is: GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I don't think bash regexp supports `\s` escape sequence.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the regex in a variable to make it work.  It was a workaround in 3.2.  Not sure why it's needed again in newer versions.

```
#!/bin/bash

line="{{ - hello dear - }}"
regex='^\{\{\s*-\s*hello\s*.*\}\}'

if [[ "${line}" =~ $regex ]]; then
     echo "got it "
fi
```

Also consider using extended pattern matching with `==` instead.  I believe it has a weaker "engine" but it's more readable sometimes.

```
shopt -s extglob
...
[[ $line == "{{ - hello dear - }}"* ]] && echo "Got it."
```

(Actually that's not even an extended pattern yet.)

Comment: **Warning!** using `\s` only works on Linux (tested on macOS, FreeBSD and Solaris)

Comment: @Fravadona What version of Bash do you use? I just tested it again with 3.2, 3.2.46, 4.0, 4.4 and latest and it works.

Comment: I see you changed your comment. Yes that might be the case for non-Linux. Regex is most likely parsed by a different engine in others.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real need to use regex here. You can just use glob matching in `bash` like this:

```sh
line="{{ - hello dear - }}"

[[ $line == '{{ - hello'*'}}' ]] && echo "got it "

got it
```